# Проблема снижения минимальной версии Android для установки приложения

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, gradle

Для планшета, на версии Android 3.2, в модуле `build.gradle` понизил `minSdkVersion` до минимально необходимого уровня - 13.

После этого, при компиляции происходит ошибка, со следующим текстом:

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 13 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0] C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\...\caches\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 13
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 13,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 14,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.appcompat" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

Если в файле `AndroidManifest.xml`, который расположен по указанному адресу, изменить строку `android:minSdkVersion="14"` с 14 на 13, то при компиляции, число снова поменяется на 14.

Как я могу понизить версию?

**Код от `build.gradle`:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.username.someapp"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Android 3.2 - жесть

Comment: У меня вопрос: Для кого вы собрались поддерживать 13 версию SDK?

Comment: Да, планшет старый, а приложение вовсе не для широких масс. Мне просто стало интересно попробовать запустить его на данном устройстве.

Comment: androidx библиотеки не поддерживают minSdkVersion < 14

Comment: Если ради интереса - попробуйте проигнорировать `minSdk` библиотек: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#override_uses-sdk_for_imported_libraries. Если очень повезёт, проект соберётся и возможно даже будет работать. Но, по-хорошему, для таких случаев нужно писать отдельную версию приложения с использованием старых версий инструментов и библиотек.